# abstraction of ValueObject

Tags: php, oop, inheritance, domain-driven-design, abstract-class

I'm trying to learn coding with ValueObject. I have question about having abstract implementation of VO and child  class extends it. Children will implement only validate method for given value (email, username etc.).
My first VO looks line below with business rules which are validating in constructor.

```
final class Email {
    private $email;

    public function __construct(string $email)
    {
        $this->validateEmail($email);

        $this->email = $email;
    }

    public function value() : string
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    private function validateEmail(string $email) : void
    {
        if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            throw new IncorrectEmailException();
        }
    }
}
```

When I was writing second VO I found some pattern where different is only validation rule (method `validate`). So I thought about some abstract class implementing pattern and let child refine validation rules.

```
abstract class ValueObject {

    protected $value;

    public function __construct($value)
    {
        $this->validate($value);

        $this->value = $value;
    }

    public function value()
    {
        return $value;
    }

    abstract protected function validate($value) : void;
}

final class Email extends ValueObject {
    protected function validate($value) : void
    {
        if (!is_string($value)) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException();
        }

        if (!filter_var($value, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            throw new IncorrectEmailException();
        }
    }
}
```

I lost typing some methods and inputs or outputs (e.g. method 'value'). PHP doesn't have generic types and I must validate value type like string. I'm not sure it is proper place to do it becaus it's not business rule (I think, but I can be wrong) Can someone tell me which option is better and is compatible with good practices?

Comment: Maybe you want to take a look at https://github.com/teneleven/valueobjects, which is a clone of https://github.com/nicolopignatelli/valueobjects.git (deleted by author).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wouldn't do that for a couple of reasons:

1. this would work only with the value objects that have only one parameter in the constructor
2. the parameter in the constructor would not follow the naming from the ubiquitous language
3. the getters would not follow the naming from the ubiquitous language
4. you won't have type hinting for the parameters in the constructor as they are unknown to the base class
5. you should avoid inheritance for domain objects unless it is absolutely necessary (it almost never is) as it couples your domain objects to other classes and the cognitive effort for the programmer is higher: one must know what the base class do in order to understand the child class; I try to [favor composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance).

You loose all this for not calling `validate()` inside your contructor.

Answer (score 5):

**Don't** use inheritance for concepts that are not related. A Value Object is not a real-world concept. It is a technique used in programs.

There is no point having an abstract base class `ValueObject` that is then extended by `Email`, `PhoneNumber`, `PostalAddress` a.s.o.

Write one class for each of these concepts and keep it simple. For example, there is no need for a separate validation method. Put the validation in constructor, implement `__toString()` (if appropriate) and/or other methods that format the encapsulated value and that should be all.

For example:

```
final class EmailAddress
{
    private $email;

    public function __construct(string $email)
    {
        if (! filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException(sprintf("Invalid email '%s'", $email));
        }

        $this->email = $email;
    }

    public function __toString() : string
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    // For some statistics
    public function getDomain() : string
    {
        // write code here to return only the part after '@'
    }
}
```